# select sql from 2 tables in a certain time frame

Tags: php, sql

I have a code that works but it does not show the timeframe that I want... it shows the complete list... I want to be able to see the last 30 days or so not the whole database please help and thanks in advance:
here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `users` t1
    LEFT JOIN `drive_routes` t2 ON t1.id = t2.driver
WHERE t2.driver IS NULL
  AND suspended = 0 AND quit = 0 AND deleted = 0
```

here is a screenshot of table structure

[image: Table structure]

Comment: Which table/column holds the datetime-value?

Comment: thanks jarth I was just fixing that

Comment: the drive_routes is a timestamp value

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which column in drive_routes? (And which data type is it?)

Comment: timestamp and the datatype is timestamp

Comment: http://prntscr.com/99uhnx

Comment: Add something like AND drive_routes  > datediff(today,-30) to the ON clause. (I don't know MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable `cutoff_date` with value `today` - `30 days`.

Then add `AND drive_routes.timestamp <= cutoff_date` to the `WHERE` clause.

If you add which database system you're using, I can update this to be more specific.

**EDIT:**

*EDIT 2:* I tested it, and this should work.

```
set @cutoff_date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY));

   SELECT t1.*
     FROM `users` t1
LEFT JOIN `drive_routes` t2 ON t2.id = t2.driver
    WHERE t2.driver IS NULL
      AND suspended = 0
      AND quit = 0
      AND deleted = 0
      AND t2.timestamp >= @cutoff_date;
```

**Relevant info:**

- [Mysql date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) (`DATE_SUB()`, `CURDATE()`)
- [Mysql DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can select 30 recent records by adding the `ORDER BY date_field_name DESC` clause and `LIMIT 30`

Comment: Aaaight, got it! Any field with a `timestamp` in the tables?

Comment: yea I know about that clause but I want 30 days

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
where `dateField` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

you can use `DAY` also:

```
where `dateField` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: @MrJohnDowe `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)` will give date like '2015-11-03'.if you are storing timestamp convert this date to time stamp then compare.you can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to do this.